# Questions about complementizers (at least, I think they're complementizers...)

Tags: syntax

1. I would like to know – there is a grammatical term for the function of the dash in this sentence, is that right?

English doesn’t have a word like *that* or *whether* that can replace the dash in that sentence, but is there any fundamental reason why it couldn't have?

2. Does the dash in:

*You don’t have to do that – it’s fine*

Have the same function as the one in the first sentence? (I feel that in the first case it could be replaced with a colon, but in the second case it would be a semicolon.)

3. Is there a term to describe the difference between:

*I would like to know whether there is a grammatical term for this* (where the question is embedded), and

*I would like to know – is there a grammatical term for this?* (where the question is stated directly).

4. Can the function of *whether* in the first sentence of Q3 be broken down the function of the dash in the second question plus another function or restriction?

Comment: I have lately taken to say [I mean](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/starting-an-independent-statement-with-i-mean)* a lot. I mean, that could replace the dash, as much as "well", except in the first example, which should maybe have a colon instead (the way you used to format 2. yourself?). But I'm affraid *discourse particle* is not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Yes - I originally put a colon but wanted to get across that there was some similarity with 2, so went with the dash as I find it acceptable in both cases. I can see how *I mean* could also work as a linker here, but what I really want is not so much examples of other possible linkers as an explanation of what kind of syntactic link there is. The first example is from Thai where a word that would generally be translated as *that* performed the function of the dash.

Comment: I was just trying to find how these discourse particles are labeled, if it would answer your question at the same time. But seems that *it depends*

Comment: I'm not sure the function has to be encoded by a discourse particle though - in English, if we are going to verbalise anything in that position it does have to be some kind of discourse particle or signpost, because there is no available complementiser - but what I'm wondering why that should be the case.